# How to close an open window, such as an open .txt or .pdf file

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium to test a website, somewhere in the website I double click on an uploaded file and a .txt file opens, how can I close this .txt file? Can I still use Selenium? or should I use some other stuff to close a .txt file?
In other words how to close a window?

Comment: Not sure how viable this may be as a solution, but what about sending the keystrokes `ALT + F4` to the opened text file?

Comment: @Anthony Forloney That was nice :) still a bit far from what I was thinking of as in this way I can not specify the exact path of the window that I want to close, but your suggestion definitely woks, would you like to post it as the answer?

Comment: I had included the suggestion as an answer but for my own sanity had also included other platform-specific keyboard shortcuts to be more qualified as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution out there, but you could try to send the keystrokes <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to force the opened application (ie, the text-file) to close. This would be applicable for Windows, other platform specific [keyboard shortcuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts) are listed below,

- Mac OS: <kbd>⌘Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>
- KDE: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Emacs: <kbd>q</kbd>
- Linux (Gnome): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl + W in case of Linux(Gnome).

Comment: @shekharsuman Thanks for the information -- I had updated the answer to reflect that keyboard shortcut.